# Object sizes when zooming in on interactive plot generated with ggplotly

Tags: r, size, zooming, interactive, ggplotly

I am preparing an interactive graph using ggplotly in R, which can be represented by the following example:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

p <- ggplot(pressure, aes(x=temperature, y=pressure)) + geom_point() + geom_line()
ggplotly(p)
```

When you zoom in on such plots, all objects (i.e., symbols and lines) keep the same size/tickness instead of getting bigger. However, I would like for the objects to become bigger when zooming in (see example images). Is this somehow possible?

[image: Example]